# millis() not working properly

Tags: millis

I'm doing a little project that, on a press of a button, will light up three LEDs and then will turn off the LEDs in different times. I'm using the `millis()` function to control the time that each LED will be on.

On the first time that I press the button, everything works fine. But the problem starts when I press the button for the second time.

If I press the button soon after the loop ends, something goes wrong and the behavior of the LED become a mess (just one or two LEDs light up in weird times). But, if I wait about 2 seconds before pressing the button for the second time, everything goes right.

Here's my code:

```
const int ledPin1 =  11;
  const int ledPin2 =  12;
  const int ledPin3 =  13;
  const int buttonPin = 2; 

  int buttonState = 0;
  long previousMillis1 = 0;
  long previousMillis2 = 0;
  long previousMillis3 = 0;

  int state = 0;

  void setup() 
  {
    pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT);   
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

    Serial.begin(9600);
  }

  void loop()
  {

       buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

       if (buttonState == HIGH) {
        state = 1;
       }

       if (state == 1)
       {
        taskExecute(3000, 2000, 4000);
       }
  }

  void taskExecute(int tMotor1, int tMotor2, int tMotor3)
  {

    int ledState1 = HIGH; 
    int ledState2 = HIGH;
    int ledState3 = HIGH; 

    digitalWrite(ledPin1, ledState1);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, ledState2);
    digitalWrite(ledPin3, ledState3);

    do
    {
      unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

      if(currentMillis - previousMillis1 > tMotor1) 
      {
        previousMillis1 = currentMillis;   

        if (ledState1 == HIGH)
          ledState1 = LOW;

        digitalWrite(ledPin1, ledState1);
      }

      if(currentMillis - previousMillis2 > tMotor2) 
      {
        previousMillis2 = currentMillis;   

        if (ledState2 == HIGH)
          ledState2 = LOW;

        digitalWrite(ledPin2, ledState2);
      }

      if(currentMillis - previousMillis3 > tMotor3) 
      {
        previousMillis3 = currentMillis;   

        if (ledState3 == HIGH)
          ledState3 = LOW;

        digitalWrite(ledPin3, ledState3);
      }
    } while (ledState1 == HIGH || ledState2 == HIGH || ledState3 == HIGH);
    state = 0;
  }
```

Other strange thing that happens is that sometimes the time that i've been set in millis for the led get on become a little different. Example: when I press the button, the LED 1 needs to light up for 3 seconds, but he lights up just 2.5 seconds.

What i'm doing wrong? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables `previousMillis` (1-3) are not properly initialised.  So if you wait a while before pressing the button, that delay time becomes part of the time that the LED is illuminated for.

If your `taskExecute()` function sets them before the loop, this will fix that:

```
void taskExecute(int tMotor1, int tMotor2, int tMotor3)
{
    int ledState1 = HIGH;
    int ledState2 = HIGH;
    int ledState3 = HIGH;

    digitalWrite(ledPin1, ledState1);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, ledState2);
    digitalWrite(ledPin3, ledState3);

    unsigned long time_now = millis();
    previousMillis1 = time_now;
    previousMillis2 = time_now;
    previousMillis3 = time_now;

    do 
    {
        ...
    } while (ledState1 == HIGH || ledState2 == HIGH || ledState3 == HIGH);
    state = 0;
}
```

On a coding-style note - I did not initially see the resetting of the global variable `state=0` at the end of the `taskExecute()` function.  It might be better to move this up to underneath the initial call to `taskExecute()` so all the `state` handling is in one place.

Comment: Perfect!!! The problem has gone! Thank you so much for the help! :)